# Saving remembered function when closing down notebook

Tags: functions, notebooks, save, dumpsave

I have functions defined to remember their values

```
f[x_]:=f[x]
```

I would like to be able to close a notebook without losing the computed values, what is the **simplest/appropriate way** to do so?

Would `DumpSave[]` work?

EDIT:

The solution in the duplicate answer doesn't mention the specific construct I'm using and is not simple, because modifying every object to include a `Once[]` statement makes the code harder to read and to mantain, hence it isn't simple.

One of the solutions proposed is to use DumpSave but doesn't provide an example of how to use it and it's not clear whether it will work in my case.

Comment: If you need help that is so specific that a generic `DumpSave` won't work, then you should explain what exactly is the problem you are facing. What about `DumpSave` doesn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure whether dumpsave will or will not work. The problem is exactly as the one in the answer but I can't test it right now and figured having this as a question is good. I'll try it when I get back to my computer tomorrow.